# Set of all Languages

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Sorry if the Question sounds a little trivial.
Let A* be the set of all languages over A={a,b}. Then A can be written as {aUb}*
which is a regular expression.So this is the set of all languages(actually set of all strings) regular.Am i thinking in the right direction.

Comment: The set of all languages is a different thing than the set of all strings. It's the same as the difference between the list `[1, 2, 3]` and `[[], [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1, 2,3]]`.

Comment: @EliRose That comment is misleading since the second list of lists is not the list of all lists over $\{1,\dots, 5\}$.

Comment: What is the question here? Maybe it's a language issue; can you please formulate a *question*?

Comment: @Raphael: You're right -- if only comments were editable.

Comment: @EliRose Done. :) (Please flag these as obsolete after reading.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need the right notation. Let's start with the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$. Then the regular expression $(a+b)$ represents a set of two strings, namely $\{a,b\}$. The expression $(a+b)^2$ represents the set of the strings $\{aa, ab, ba, bb\}$. The expression $(a+b)^3 \ldots$ The expression $\{a,b\}^*$, also denoted $\Sigma^*$, represents the union of all these sets. Each of these sets is called a *language*, and so $\Sigma^*$ is also a language. So $\Sigma^*$ is *one* language, not the set of all languages, over the alphabet $\Sigma$, and it contains all the strings you can form out of that alphabet.

The set of all languages you can form using that alphabet is the *power set* of $\Sigma^*$, denoted by $\mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*) = \{L | L \subseteq \Sigma^*\}$. That is, if $L$ contains only strings from your alphabet, then $L$ is a language over $\Sigma$, so $L$ is an element of the set $\mathcal{P}(\Sigma^*)$. Now, some of these languages are regular, and some are not. Certainly the language $\Sigma^*$ is a regular language, and $\emptyset$ is a regular language (you can draw their finite automata and see that they are the two simplest automata). Other languages, such as $\{a^nb^m|n+m \text{ is prime}\}$ are not regular. I hope that clears some things up.

Comment: Minor nit: your first paragraph didn't mention that the empty string is in $\{a,b\}^*$.